# Using overriden method

Tags: java, arraylist

In the terms of the task i need to override `toString` method to return each second element of the `ArrayList`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    String str = "";
    for (int y = 1; y <= list.size() - 2; y += 2) {
        str += list.get(y) + " ";
    }
    return str;
}
```

But when i try to call it from another method to print saved string value:

```
public void print() {
    System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```

It prints me all elements of the array like this: [0, 1, 2, 3 , 4, 5].

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where (in which class) did you override toString?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't quite enough code included to be sure, but there are 2 possible problems:

1. The method shown in your answer is not inside of a class the extends ArrayList. This is the only way to properly override a method
2. list is not instantiated as an object of the class you created. If you instantiated list as an ArrayList, creating a new class would have no affect.

A new class must be created and list must be a member of the new class.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override a method you have to create your own class.  For example:

```
public class MyList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyList() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        for (int y = 1; y < super.size(); y += 2) {
            str += super.get(y) + " ";
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

If you instantiate `MyList` you will see what you want.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    MyList<String> list = new MyList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output:

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

Alternatively and probably a better approach would be to simply define the method taking in a parameter and calling it.

```
public String toString(Collection<?> list) {
    String str = "";
    for (int y = 1; y < super.size(); y += 2) {
        str += super.get(y) + " ";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
System.out.println(toString(list));
```

Comment: If you use y <= super.size() - 2. You can test 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 --> Output is 1,3,5 --- Wrong

Comment: I was copying his implementation, you are correct.  I'll fix it.

Comment: You wrong again. Not y <= super.size(). Must be y < super.size()

Comment: Fixed.  I was focusing on his question, not the algorithm itself.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not overwrite the `toString` from the `ArrayList` class but just the default `toString` from your own class. This method will only be called if you do `myclass.toString()`.

Also why try to do this by overwriting `toString`? This will have effect on your whole project so you will not be able to use the default `toString` in other classes.

Just create a function that returns the required String?

```
public String customArrayListToString(ArrayList<> list){
    String str = "";
    for (int y = 1; y <= list.size()-1; y += 2) {
        str += list.get(y) + " ";
    }
    return str;
}
```

or do as posted in an other answer and create your own class that extends `ArrayList`

Comment: If you Override the toString from ArrayList, it overrides toString from object...

Comment: If you use y <= list.size() - 2. You can test 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 --> Output is 1,3,5 --- Wrong

Comment: You wrong again. Not y <= list.size(). Must be y < list.size()

Comment: You are right Loc, updated it.
@Yassin, obviously since toString from the ArrayList class overwrites the one from Object you overwrite the Object one if you overwrite the one in ArrayList... changed the answer to prevent misunderstandings

Answer (score -1):

You have to override the `toString` in the class you want to use it, otherwise the non-overriden method is invoked, because the class otherwise invokes the default ` consturctor and it's methods. .